# What happened to tortoisehg-nautilus in 12.04?

Tags: package-management, mercurial

When I run `sudo apt-get install tortoisehg-nautilus` under Ubuntu 12.04 I get:

```
E: Unable to locate package tortoisehg-nautilus
```

The same command works under Ubuntu 10.04 and I get full nautilus integration. I tried installing `tortoisehg` and using the `ppa:tortoisehg-ppa/releases` PPA but I don't see any nautilus integration. Right clicking on folders does not bring up a TortoiseHg menu item, nor do I see icon overlays for Hg repositories. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to this bug on the tortoisehg tracker](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issue/869/tortoisehg-nautilus-doesnt-work-at-all), there was an issue with nautilus integration. It appears to be fixed in the upstream version now. This is likely something worthy of getting an update for precise to fix the bug.

Try installing the package as a one-off installation from quantal.
Here's a [direct link](http://mirrors.us.kernel.org/ubuntu//pool/universe/t/tortoisehg/tortoisehg-nautilus_2.4-2_all.deb) to the current deb package. This may get updated, so if it fails, use the [ubuntu package search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=tortoisehg-nautilus&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) to find the current version and install it that way. If that doesn't work, you can apply the patch mentioned manually in the bug report.

Comment: FYI: this was removed in Precise.  It no longer exists in the repositories.

Comment: @LordofTime It is back in Quantal

Comment: @fluteflute the reason i mentioned it was removed from Precise was so that "getting an update for precise" wouldnt mean additional bug reports for updates (because it doesnt exist in Precise).  As well, any updates or sync requests or backports will need extensive testing to be included in Precise.

Comment: @LordofTime: What was removed in Precise? The "tortoisehg-nautilus" package? Why? Where should I ask? :)

Comment: @Gili, the package you're looking for was removed in Precise.  I do not know why it was removed, nor do I know where you should ask.  but what fluteflute said is right, it is in Quantal.

Answer (score 1):

The link is not working anymore...

So try this : http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/all/tortoisehg-nautilus/download

Pick a mirror of your choice.

Then install the package. In my case the installation failed, but the nautilus integration start working.

Comment: I recommend updating the link in the accepted answer.

Comment: It failed for me as well, something about a python script that already existed, but it works fine.

Comment: @Gili, I would add commment on the accepted answer, but I don't have reputation for that yet :(

Comment: I thought maybe we could create a PPA for tortoisehg-nautilus... I don't know how to do it, but I could read a bit about that. It must be just a repackaging of the Quantal package since it just a single python file that is contained in this package...